# Looping Register-ArgumentCompleter produces incorrect parameter completions

Tags: powershell

I have a module with a hashtable of dynamically derived enum values, that I thought would be slick to incorporate into Register-ArgumentCompleter for tab completion.

The motivation here is that I can't directly set the module function's input parameters to autoconvert into the enum type (which would properly enable tab completion), because I wish to dynamically derive the enums to save users from manually managing the enum values, as well as due to limitations with the .NET implementation of enums -- I need to allow for strings with dashes or starting with numbers, and potentially null values, all of which enums sadly don't allow. My idea is to do a workaround by adding tab-completed parameter values via Register-ArgumentCompleter.

**Problem:** I build this workaround as a script that's loaded in the first position of the ScriptsToProcess member of the module manifest, whereupon I discovered that incorrect values are being set when I loop over the hashtable keys and run Register-ArgumentCompleter.

Sample code to reproduce:

```
function test {param($a, $b, $c, $d )}

$ht = @{
    '1' = @('a', @('a1','a2'))
    '2' = @('b', @('b1','b2'))
    '3' = @('c', @('c1','c2'))
    '4' = @('d', @('d1','d2'))
}

Foreach ($enum in $ht.Keys){
    $paramName = $ht.$enum[0]
    $paramValue = $ht.$enum[1]

    write-host $paramName
    write-host $paramValue

    Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName test2 -ParameterName $paramName -ScriptBlock {$paramValue}
}

PS> test -a <tab>
b1 b2
```

This is PS 7.2.5. In Windows PowerShell 5.1.19041 I get `c1` `c2` as suggested values. You can see from the host writes that it's down to whichever key is parsed last in the ht loop.

I also tried `$ht.["$enum"][0|1]` to cast the key type explicitly to a string, to no avail. When I write-host in the loop, all the values seem correct.

Does this seem like an error from me or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the loop completes, `$enum` will have a value of whatever the last key in its sort order is.

Use [`ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure) to close over the value of `$ht` and `$enum` by the time `GetNewClosure()` is called, making the scriptblock retain the original values of `$ht` and `$enum`:

```
function test {param($a, $b, $c, $d )}

$ht = @{
    '1' = @('a', @('a1','a2'))
    '2' = @('b', @('b1','b2'))
    '3' = @('c', @('c1','c2'))
    '4' = @('d', @('d1','d2'))
}

Foreach ($enum in $ht.Keys){
    Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName test -ParameterName $ht.$enum[0] -ScriptBlock { $ht.$enum[1] }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

FWIW you can simplify the `$ht` table significantly:

```
$ht = @{
    'a' = @('a1','a2')
    'b' = @('b1','b2')
    'c' = @('c1','c2')
    'd' = @('d1','d2')
}

Foreach ($enum in $ht.Keys){
    Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName test -ParameterName $enum -ScriptBlock { $ht[$enum] }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I thought that was only for psobjects. I didn't know scriptblocks also had this. Especially since in my edit I explicitly rederive the script block values in a separate variable.

Comment: Thanks for the ht suggestion as well. I actually have that roundabout way because the enum name is different from the function parameter name, so I have the $ht keys set to the enum name and the first element of the value set to the parameter name.

Comment: @Blaisem in that case you might want to use a hashtable for the inner values too: `$ht = @{ '1' = @{ Name = 'a'; Values = 'a1','a2', ...}}`